# Confusing caching issue-DNS

Tags: dns, cache

Yesterday I changed my DNS servers to point to a different server.  This change has still not been displayed on my own computer, but it does from other computers around the world (checked using browsershots.org)  I'm using OpenDNS for my DNS and there cache is pointing to the correct server.

What could be meaning my computer still isn't going to the right place?

Thank you!

Comment: OK, so now I'm really confused!  When I type in just my site's address, it goes to the old version, but when I type in example.com/index.html it all works perfectly, as do all the other pages...?!

Answer (score 1):

It takes a while for changes to ripple around the world, so I'd give it a bit longer. Another possibility is that you have a hosts file (in /etc/hosts or c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts depending on your operating system) that has the IP address hardcoded in it.

Comment: OK, will leave it longer.  Just checked hosts file and it's not there.  Where would it be being slow to get to me though if OpenDNS is showing the right one and it's not cached on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone should see the updated record change somewhere between instantly and the relevant TTL value set on the record. But in practice they don't and you experience what you are seeing.

A lot of ISP's don't honour the Time to Live [TTL value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) and hold on to the old record for longer, some badly configured caches may not see the change if the TTL value is very low as they ignore TTL's below a certain value.

I have also seen a DNS change come into effect on a machine then a couple of hours later it reverts back again and flip flops for a while like this. Very confusing.

It might be worthwhile flushing your machines DNS. This can sometimes help speed up the change

ipconfig /flushdns

if you are on windows.